# Maven 3 plugin - How to programatically exclude a dependency and all its transitive dependencies?

Tags: java, maven, maven-3, maven-plugin

I'm developing a Maven 3 plugin and I want to exclude some dependencies, and their transitive dependencies, when a configuration is set to `true` in the plugin.

I don't want to use `<exclusions>` in the POM itself, even in a profile. I want to exclude those dependencies *programatically*. In fact, what I want is to prevent the dependency jars to be included in the final war (I'm building a war), when a plugin configuration is set to `true`.

I tried :

```
@Mojo(requiresDependencyResolution=ResolutionScope.COMPILE, name="compileHook",defaultPhase=LifecyclePhase.COMPILE)
public class compileHook extends AbstractMojo
{
    @Override
    public void execute() throws MojoExecutionException, MojoFailureException
    {
        // ...
        Set<Artifact> artifacts = this.project.getArtifacts();
        for(Artifact artifact : artifacts)
        {
            if("org.package.to.remove".equalsIgnoreCase(artifact.getGroupId()))
            {
                artifact.setScope("provided");
            }
        }
        // ...
    }
}
```

Since this occures at the `compile` phase, it will indeed remove the artifacts with a group id "org.package.to.remove" from having their jars included in the war when packaged. But ***this doesn't remove the transitive artifacts those dependencies add***!

What is the best way to programatically remove some dependencies, and their transitive dependencies, from being included in a final .jar/.war?

Comment: The first question which comes to my mind: Why do you need a plugin if there is already maven-war-plugin ? What is not as you need it ? Apart from that it sounds really strange if you hard code things to exclude which is completely against the Maven idea to declare or exclude dependencies within the POM. This would be only visible to those who know your plugin. If you only see the pom.xml you will be lost. You might need to set the scope for such kind of dependencies to provided ?

Comment: khmarbaise, thanks for the help. I prefere not to go in depth about why I need to do that. But be sure I agree with what you say, but I still need to do it programatically!

Comment: what you are describing sound a lot like a maven profile, can you give us any more detail on what you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: Allen, as I said I prefere not to go into too much details about why I want to do that. If the question itself is not clear enough though, please tell me and I'll update it! Thanks for the help.